# Unexpected convergence of calculated values, can you help me figure out why?

Tags: c++, physics, physics-engine

I am writing a molecular dynamics program to create an lattice and populate it with atoms/molecules. These then are given random velocities and the system is initialized. Then throughout time the molecules interact with each other and exert forces on each other.

I've tried to make my program as readable as possible.

My issue is when the code is run, the values of everything I'm interested in, mainly the vectors _tempreture, _pressure, _totalEnergy, _interactionEnergy, _kineticEnergy all seem to converge (after 5 runs) to certain values. These values then do not change throughout the rest of the runs and sometimes will randomly spike, then drop back down.

I can't figure out the unexpected behavior of my code, and I've been looking at it hours upon hours. I hoping one of you bright guys will be able to help me.

```
//in MD.h

#ifndef MD_H
#define MD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class MD{
public:
    MD();
    ~MD();
    void initLatice();
    void simulate(int _runs);
    void wrtieToFile(std::string fileName);
    double randomValue(double upper, double lower);
private:
    double _nMolecules;
    double _estKineticEnergy;
    double _dt;
    double _density;
    bool _tempscale;
    double _energyCorrection;
    double _pressureCorrection;
    double _nFCC = 4;
    double _truncationSeperation;
    double _sidelength;
    double _pi = 3.142;
    std::vector<double> x_data, y_data, z_data;
    std::vector<double> _vX, _vY, _vZ;
    std::vector<double> _xPos, _yPos, _zPos;
    std::vector<double> _totalEnergy, _kineticEnergy, _interactionEnergy, _pressure, _tempreture;
    std::vector<double> _radialDist, _radialDistCoord;
};

#endif
```

in case anyone is wondering the next file doesn't contain the definition for writeToFile, I decided not to paste it on here to save space.

```
//in MD.cpp
#include "MD.h"

MD::MD() : _radialDist(201, 0.0), _radialDistCoord(201, 0.0) {
        _dt = 0.005;
        _density = 1.0;
        _tempscale = true;
        _nMolecules = pow(_nFCC, 3) * 4;
        x_data = { 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.25 };
        y_data = { 0.25, 0.75, 0.25, 0.75 };
        z_data = { 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75 };
        _sidelength = pow((_nFCC / _density), 1. / 3.);
        _truncationSeperation = 2.5;
        if (_truncationSeperation > _sidelength / 2.0)
            _truncationSeperation = _sidelength / 2.0;
        _energyCorrection = (8.0 * _pi * _density)*(1.0 / (9.0 * pow(_truncationSeperation, 9)) - 1 / (3.0 * pow(_truncationSeperation, 3)));
        _pressureCorrection = (16.0 * _pi * pow(_density, 2))*(2.0 / (9.0 * pow(_truncationSeperation, 9)) - 1 / (3.0 * pow(_truncationSeperation, 3)));
}

MD::~MD(){}

double MD::randomValue(double upper, double lower)
{
    double returnValue;
    do{
        returnValue = upper + (rand() / (RAND_MAX / (lower - upper)));
    } while (returnValue > upper || returnValue < lower);
    return returnValue;
}

void MD::initLatice(){
    int count = 0;
    double x_init = 0, y_init = 0, z_init = 0;
    double _tempreture = 1.0;
    _estKineticEnergy = 0.5 * (3.0 * _nMolecules - 4.0) * _tempreture;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int a = 1; a <= _nFCC; a++){
            for (int b = 1; b <= _nFCC; b++){
                for (int c = 1; c <= _nFCC; c++){
                    _xPos.push_back(_sidelength*(a - 1 + x_data[i]) / _nFCC);
                    _vX.push_back(randomValue(0.5, -0.5));
                    x_init += _vX[count] / _nMolecules;

                    _yPos.push_back(_sidelength*(b - 1 + y_data[i]) / _nFCC);
                    _vY.push_back(randomValue(0.5, -0.5));
                    y_init += _vY[count] / _nMolecules;

                    _zPos.push_back(_sidelength*(c - 1 + z_data[i]) / _nFCC);
                    _vZ.push_back(randomValue(0.5, -0.5));
                    z_init += _vZ[count] / _nMolecules;

                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    double velocityScale = 0, kineticEnergy = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < _nMolecules; i++){
        _vX[i] -= x_init;
        _vY[i] -= y_init;
        _vZ[i] -= z_init;
        kineticEnergy += 0.5 * (pow(_vX[i], 2) + pow(_vY[i], 2) + pow(_vZ[i], 2));
    }

    velocityScale = sqrt(_estKineticEnergy / kineticEnergy);

    for (int i = 0; i < _nMolecules; i++){
        _vX[i] = _vX[i] * velocityScale;
        _vY[i] = _vY[i] * velocityScale;
        _vZ[i] = _vZ[i] * velocityScale;
    }
}

void MD::simulate(int _runs){
    double force = 0;
    double seperationSquared = 0;
    double interactionEnergy = 0;
    double kineticEnergy = 0;
    double pressure = 0;

    for (int run = 0; run <= _runs; run++){
        interactionEnergy = 0;
        pressure = 0;
        std::vector<double> force_x(256, 0.0);
        std::vector<double> force_y(256, 0.0);
        std::vector<double> force_z(256, 0.0);

        for (int i = 0; i < _nMolecules - 1; i++){
            double xI = _xPos[i], yI = _yPos[i], zI = _zPos[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < _nMolecules; j++){
                double x = xI - _xPos[j];
                double y = yI - _yPos[j];
                double z = zI - _zPos[j];

                if (x > _sidelength / 2.0)
                    x -= _sidelength;
                if (y > _sidelength / 2.0)
                    y -= _sidelength;
                if (z > _sidelength / 2.0)
                    z -= _sidelength;
                if (x < -_sidelength / 2.0)
                    x += _sidelength;
                if (y < -_sidelength / 2.0)
                    y += _sidelength;
                if (z < -_sidelength / 2.0)
                    z += _sidelength;

                seperationSquared = pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) + pow(z, 2);

                if (seperationSquared <= (pow(_truncationSeperation, 2))){
                    interactionEnergy += 4. * ((1. / pow(seperationSquared, 6)) - (1. / pow(seperationSquared, 3)));
                    force = 24. * ((2. / pow(seperationSquared, 7)) - (1. / pow(seperationSquared, 4)));
                    force_x[i] += x * force;
                    force_y[i] += y * force;
                    force_z[i] += z * force;
                    force_x[j] -= x * force;
                    force_y[j] -= y * force;
                    force_z[j] -= z * force;
                    pressure += force * seperationSquared;

                    int histCounter = ceil(sqrt(seperationSquared) * (200.0/_truncationSeperation));
                    _radialDist[histCounter] += 1.0;
                }
            }
        }

        //thermostating
        double velocityScale = 0;

        if (_tempscale == true){
            kineticEnergy = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < _nMolecules; i++)
                kineticEnergy += 0.5 * (pow(_vX[i], 2) + pow(_vY[i], 2) + pow(_vZ[i], 2));
            velocityScale = sqrt(_estKineticEnergy / kineticEnergy);
        } 
        else { velocityScale = 1.0; }

        kineticEnergy = 0;

        //applying verlets leapfrog algorithm
        for (int i = 0; i < _nMolecules; i++){
            _vX[i] = _vX[i] * velocityScale + force_x[i] * _dt;
            _xPos[i] += _vX[i] * _dt;

            _vY[i] = _vY[i] * velocityScale + force_y[i] * _dt;
            _yPos[i] += _vY[i] * _dt;

            _vZ[i] = _vZ[i] * velocityScale + force_z[i] * _dt;
            _zPos[i] += _vZ[i] * _dt;

            kineticEnergy += 0.5 * (pow(_vX[i], 2) + pow(_vY[i], 2) + pow(_vZ[i], 2));

            //check if the particle is still within the box
            if (_xPos[i] > _sidelength)
                _xPos[i] -= _sidelength;
            if (_yPos[i] > _sidelength)
                _yPos[i] -= _sidelength;
            if (_zPos[i] > _sidelength)
                _zPos[i] -= _sidelength;
            if (_xPos[i] < 0.0)
                _xPos[i] += _sidelength;
            if (_yPos[i] < 0.0)
                _yPos[i] += _sidelength;
            if (_zPos[i] < 0.0)
                _zPos[i] += _sidelength;
        }

        _kineticEnergy.push_back(kineticEnergy / _nMolecules);
        _interactionEnergy.push_back((interactionEnergy / _nMolecules) + _energyCorrection);
        _totalEnergy.push_back(_kineticEnergy[run] + _interactionEnergy[run]);

        if (_tempscale == true)
            _tempreture.push_back(_nMolecules * 2. * _kineticEnergy[run] / (3.0 * _nMolecules - 4.0));
        else
            _tempreture.push_back(_nMolecules * 2. * _kineticEnergy[run] / (3.0 * _nMolecules - 3.0));

        _pressure.push_back((2.0 * _kineticEnergy[run] * _nMolecules + pressure) / (3.0*(pow(_sidelength, 3) + _pressureCorrection)));
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++){
        double r = i * _truncationSeperation / 200.0;
        _radialDistCoord[i] = _radialDistCoord[i - 1] + 2.0 * _radialDist[i] * 10 / _runs / _nMolecules;
        _radialDist[i] = _radialDist[i] / (2.0*_pi*r*r*(_truncationSeperation/200.0)*_density*_runs*_nMolecules);
    }


}
```

and finally...

```
//in main.cpp
#include "MD.h"

int main(){
    MD myMD;
    myMD.initLatice();
    myMD.simulate(400);
    std::string fileName = "myFile.txt";
    myMD.wrtieToFile(fileName);
    return 0;
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the super helpful comment, I am aware that the debugger exists. I've used it and haven't been able to pinpoint the problem. I'm wondering if there was something simple I've overlooked.

Comment: McKenzie boooooyyyyy

Comment: You _would_ expect this to converge so each molecule in the box ends up with the same equilibrium value, but not after 5 time-steps. You need to work out analytically (with pen and paper), @ what time scale you expect convergence to equilibrium (use equipartition or some alt. simple representation). Then, you will need to set your time-steps according to the crossing-time of the domain, that is, the time-step must be less than the time it takes for the fastest molecule to traverse the grid. This will ensure you are correctly capturing collisions and are not getting some time-averaged solution.

Comment: You can also work out (again using equipartition theorem), what the converges pressure and temperature is. After the code converges (using a sensible time-step), compare the values, they should match to a good tolerance.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all your help, I figured out my problem. I have the wrong equation of density at the beginning thus giving me completely wrong values. After correcting this my code works fine, and plots in python look as beautiful as my bed right now.